# Find records where CSV column values match

Tags: mysql

I am making a website. In the database I have a table of articles that kind of looks like this:

```
id | name    | cats                           | etc.
------------------------------------------------------
1  | "alice" | "this, that, those, them"      | 
2  | "bob"   | "this, that, those"            |
3  | "carol" | "this, banana, cupcake"        |
4  | "dave"  | "other, unrelated, words"      |
5  | "errol" | "those, them, fishstick"       |
```

When viewing an article I want to also show some of the most related articles, based on the amount of categories in common.

For example, if I was viewing the Alice article I would want to pick out (in order of preference) Bob (3 cats in common), Errol(2), Carol(1).

I am aware that this would be easier if the data was normalised (I could for example do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717093/mysql-find-related-articles)) but unfortunately that's not really an option.

Comment: You'd better change structure of your database. Take a look at [many-to-many relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)).

Comment: Why is normalization not an option? That's really the only way to do this, short of writing a string parse/compare procedure in MySQL script (which is NOT fun, I promise).

Comment: This wouldn't be too bad if you pushed it out to PHP, Perl or similar. If you have to have a MySQL-only answer then a stored proc or string parsing function is probably your only answer. @General_Mayhem is right about the excitement level. Lots of examples around though.

Comment: @ethrbunny: You could of course push it out to your script layer, but then why are you using the database in the first place? May as well just store everything in plaintext if you're going to be re-indexing it yourself.

Comment: It sounds like the OP is stuck with the current DB storage and schema. If it could be changed then I would start by what @PLB said and restructure it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. I guess it's time for some refactoring then. @General_Mayhem this is an addition to an existing site. If this was reasonably achievable as-is I would save a lot of time by not changing the structure. The database is relatively small so query speed isn't too important (within reason). If I had created the database I would have done it this way to begin with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a couple of extra tables and populating them with properly normalized data every time something was saved. These run alongside the existing tables so it's not the cleanest of solutions but it works and the query speeds are excellent.