# Finding related article based on multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717093/mysql-find-related-articles) but with a difference: I have eight different types of tags.

Something like this:

```
videos      [id, title]
tags1       [id, tag]
tags2       [id, tag]
tags3       [id, tag]
tags4       [id, tag]
tags5       [id, tag]
tags6       [id, tag]
tags7       [id, tag]
tags8       [id, tag]
video_tags1 [vid_id, tag_id]
video_tags2 [vid_id, tag_id]
video_tags3 [vid_id, tag_id]
video_tags4 [vid_id, tag_id]
video_tags5 [vid_id, tag_id]
video_tags6 [vid_id, tag_id]
video_tags7 [vid_id, tag_id]
video_tags8 [vid_id, tag_id]
```

Given a single video.id I want to pick out related videos based on which have the most tags in common. I'm finding it hard to find a way to do this, let alone a way that won't bring the server to it's knees.

Comment: i already posted a solution, but maybe it could be simplified a lot. what does `tag` contain? only a description? so maybe i could just check if `tag_id` are equals, and there's no need to join `tags` tables.

Comment: Yes tag contains a short string - joining the tag tables isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change your database model then these proposal may fit you.

Redefine your tables in this way :

```
videos      [id, title]
tags    [id, tag_type,tag]
videos_tags [vid_id, tag_id]
```

you may also add a tag_type table (which will have 8 rows, one for each of yourtag types) for more consistency.

Then this query (it may has some syntax error, but my intention is that you get the idea) will give you the video ids and the number of matching tags with the one provided :

```
select 
       videos.id, count(videos.id) as nEqualTags 
from 
       videos videos inner join  video_tags vtags on  (vtags.vid_id=videos.id )
where 
       vtags.tag_id in (select tag_id from videos_tags where vt.id = ?) 
group by 
       videos.id 
order by 
       nEqualTags desc
```

You may add some more logic in order to cut down the results if the `nEqualTags` is lower than certain value.

(And also consider adding some index for better performance).

Hope it helps

Comment: I can change the structure. Not sure why I didn't think of this to begin with... Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about the performance it will have. If you dont mind, please update when you test it, as I am curious about it.

Comment: 0.0137s with 359 video records and 1497 video-tag records. Much better than the CPU-melting monstrosity I had before! Thanks!

Comment: Actually just ran it a couple more times and it seems to have settled at 0.0007! Beautiful.

Comment: One minor change: I added "AND videos.id != ?" to exclude the selected video.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's always a good idea to work on normalized table, and in this case this UNION queries could help:

```
(select 1 as tab, vid_id, tag_id from video_tags1
 union select 2 as tab, vid_id, tag_id from video_tags2
 union select 3 as tab, vid_id, tag_id from video_tags3
 ...)
```

Now you have to use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  tags_1.vid_id, count(*) as common_tags
FROM
  (big union above) video_tags
  INNER JOIN
  (big union above) video_tags_1
  ON video_tags.tab = video_tags_1.tab
  AND video_tags.tags_id = video_tags_1.tags_id
  AND video_tags.vid_id = 1
  AND video_tags_1.vid_id <> 1
GROUP BY video_tags_1.vid_id
ORDER BY common_tags DESC
```

This will return all of the records ordered DESC by the number of tags they have in common. This could be an idea of how to proceed. You should add one more JOIN to obtain the title of the video.
If you also need to obtain the description of the tags they have in common... well it's possible but i think it would complicate the query a lot!

Are you sure you can't change your database model, and use just a table for tags and one for video tags? It would make things a lot easier!