# improving MySQL related articles query

Tags: mysql

For a related topic list I use a query using tags. It displays a list of 5 articles that have 1 or more tags in common and that are older than the viewed one.

Is it possible to write a query that produce more relevant results by giving more weight to articles that have 2,3,4... tags in common?

I saw this topic on more or less the same subject:
[MySQL Find Related Articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717093/mysql-find-related-articles)

but it *produces 0 results in the case there are less than 3 tags in common*.

The query I use now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
AAmessage.message_id, AAmessage.title, AAmessage.date 
FROM
AAmessage
LEFT JOIN
AAmessagetagtable 
AS child ON child.message_id = AAmessage.message_id 
JOIN AAmessagetagtagtable 
AS parent ON parent.tag_id = child.tag_id 
AND
parent.message_id = '$message_id' 
AND AAmessage.date < '$row[date]' 
ORDER BY 
AAmessage.date DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

using tables:

```
AAmessage (message_id, title, date...)

AAmessagetable (key, message_id, tag_id)

AAtag (tag_id, tag.... not used in this query but needed to store names of tags)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please excuse that I changed the table names a bit to `message` and `message_tag` for readability.

Second, I didn't test this. Use it rather as a pointer than a definite answer.

The query uses two subqueries, which might not be so efficient, there is probably a room for improvement. First, the innermost query looks for the tags of the current message. Then, the middle query looks for messages which are marked with at least one common tag. The grouping is used to get unique message_id and order them by number of common tags. Last, the `JOIN` is used to load additional details and to filter out the old messages.

You may notice I used question marks instead of `'$xyz'`. This is to avoid the care about escaping the variable contents.

```
SELECT message_id, title, date
FROM message
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT message_id, COUNT(*)
            FROM message_tag
            WHERE tag_id IN 
                (SELECT MT.tag_id FROM message_tag MT WHERE MT.message_id = ?)
            GROUP BY message_id
            ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) RELATED_MESSAGES
            ON message.message_id = RELATED_MESSAGES.message_id
WHERE date < ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [HAVING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) for this situations.

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.message_id, m.title, m.date 
FROM AAmessage AS `m`
LEFT JOIN AAmessagetagtable AS `mt` ON mt.message_id = mt.message_id
GROUP m.message_id
HAVING COUNT(mt.key) >= 1
WHERE m.message_id = '$message_id' 
AND m.date < '$row[date]'
ORDER BY m.date DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Please test it and let me know