# Query collections intersections

Tags: java, jpa

I have two persisted entities with EclipseLink : Release and Style. Each Release has a Set of Style.

How to get with a NamedQuery all Release which have at least one Style in common with a particular Release ?

It would be something like

```
SELECT r1 FROM Release r1, Release r2
WHERE INTERSECT(r1.styles, r2.styles) NOT EMPTY AND r2.id = :release_id
```

but I don't know if it is possible nor finding the good syntax.

Thanks

Comment: I think its not a straight forward to achieve this directly using `JPA`. First you need to find the right query in native sql and then try to convert that to `JQL`. Here is more or less a simliar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783136/improving-mysql-related-articles-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research I don't think is is possible to do it in pure JQL (or more generally in SQL), it needs a first loop to generate the WHERE conditions.

So I ended up using Criteria API (just discovered) :

```
Set<Style> releaseStyles = em.find(Release.class, release_id).getStyles();

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Release> query = cb.createQuery(Release.class);
Root<Release> root = query.from(Release.class);
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

Expression<Integer> key = root.get("id");
Expression<Set<Style>> field = root.get("styles");

for (Style style : releaseStyles) {
  predicates.add(cb.isMember(cb.literal(style), field));
}

query.select(root).where(cb.and(
  cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])),
  cb.notEqual(key, release_id)
));

query.distinct(true);
query.groupBy(key);

return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```